# Deleting Duplicates but keep the earliest date

Tags: php, mysql

Somehow my database table duplicated a bunch of values based on a field called kdaccount.

What I'm trying to do is delete all duplicate kdaccounts with the exception of one, and I want that one to be the earliest submitted date.

I wrote a query to identify the duplicate accounts, but I'm now sure how to structure the mysql query to delete them.

```
$getVendors = mysql_query("SELECT vendor, nameid, kdaccount, MIN(dw_vendors.submitteddate) as `smallestDate` 
                                                FROM pr_po_main 
                                                LEFT JOIN dw_vendors ON pr_po_main.vendor = dw_vendors.kdaccount 
                                                WHERE dw_vendors.submitteddate <> '' GROUP BY vendor HAVING COUNT(dw_vendors.kdaccount) > '1'") or die("Get Vendors: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: You should look into using PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements as the mysql_ functions have been deprecated

Comment: Are you wanting to delete rows from both tables or just one?

Comment: `DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (<Your select modified to only return ID>)` Replace ID with whatever primary key, and try it in a testing environment first. This is assuming your SELECT only returns the duplicates, not the originals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following solution will help you,

1.create a duplicate table of dw_vendors

CREATE TABLE dw_vendors_dup LIKE dw_vendors

2.make the kdaccount as unique

```
ALTER TABLE dw_vendors_dup ADD UNIQUE (kdaccount);
```

3.insert the existing values to the new table ignoring the duplicates

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO dw_vendors_dup (vendor, nameid, kdaccount, submitteddate) 
SELECT vendor, nameid, kdaccount, submitteddate FROM dw_vendors
ORDER BY submitteddate
```

4.delete the old table dw_vendors
and rename the duplicate one to dw_vendors

Answer (score 0):

Here posted an exemple on how to achieve that on Sql Fiddle

[Linky link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac2d1/1)

That should show you the principle of the thing

Just in case here is the code

```
DELETE Test 
FROM Test 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MIN(comp) AS compMin, groupval
                FROM Test
                GROUP BY groupval) AS Test2 
ON Test.groupval = Test2.groupval AND Test.comp <> Test2.compmin
WHERE Test2.groupval IS NOT NULL
```

Table def is has follow

```
CREATE TABLE Test 
    (
        comp int, 
        groupval int 
    );
```

Edit:That should work without the having clause btw